# Uploading Images without using ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, image

I don't want to have to configure imagemagick but want to use a gem to be able to upload a picture from a form and put it into a database.  Are there other options out there?  I tried dragonfly and carrierwave but they require ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0):

I often use [Blitline](http://www.blitline.com/) which allows we to me to make any edits to the image (if needed) and then I have Blitline store it in an [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket and place the image url in my database to save space in the database.